# Updating navigation in Viewcontrollers - Coredats

Tags: swift, core-data, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I am a new programmer using Swift.
In my project I am using coredata, and a lot of view controllers.

I have this view controllers:

Viewcontroller1 has my home Viewcontroller (VC1).
Viewcontroller2 (VC2), with a list of items reloaded from my coredata (in a table view).
Viewcontroller2 (VC3), lists the attributes of the selected item in VC2.
Viewcontroller2 (VC4), makes the user edit the attributes of selected item in VC2.

SO this is my navigation: VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 -> VC4.

The problem:
Lets say I am in VC1 and go to VC2.
I now choose an item from view controller and it takes me to VC3 (I push VC3).
I am now in the item characteristics. which are listed from coredata.
To edit them I made a button, with a segue, VC4, where I made a view where the user can change the values of the choosen item. Once the user introduces any changes in the text fields, I do a NSFetchRequest, and update the values like this:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Simulator")

    do {

        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0 {

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

                result.setValue(designLabel.text, forKey: "designation")
                result.setValue(typeLabel.text, forKey: "type")
                result.setValue(localLabel.text, forKey: "local")     
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    print("Error updating")
                }


            }
        }
    } catch {

        print ("Error")
    }
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

So now, by pressing saveButton I update local, designation and type atributes, and than pop VC3.
Now in VC3 I expected to receive the update values. Instead I am receiving the old values. This is what I have in VC3:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    map.delegate = self

    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Simulator> = Simulator.fetchRequest()

    do{
        let searchResults = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

        for result in searchResults as [Simulator]{

            if (String(describing: result.objectID) == choosenID)
            {
                self.title = result.designation
                localLabel.text = "Local: \(result.local!)"
                typeLabel.text =  "Type: \(result.type!)
                print("I found it") //to check if I go inside this = and I go inside (true)

            {
        }
    }
    catch{
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

   }      
}
```

Now I press the back button and I go to VC2: some thing. The cell, which have the designation on a label still don't updated it.
So I go to VC! using back button.
Now If I move forward to VC2 or VC3 everything Is updated.

What it's happening? Why isn't it updating when I pop from VC4 to VC3?

Comment: Have you tried reloading the data when you go back?

Comment: I think I know why. I am not updating data where I should...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go back you are going back to the view as it was, when you go forward you are reloading it. What you can do though is reload the data when you go back.

Comment: I see. How can I do that? Can you tell me please?

Comment: Well it sounds like you have a tableview which you need to update the datasource for from viewWillAppear or an observer and then just call tableview.reloadData()

Comment: but i dont have any tableview in VC4 or VC3. I only have table view in VC2. So why isnt it updating in when I come for VC4 to VC3? I pop VC3 and I have the written code above in VC3, in func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool). It should work no?  I am fetching again for results...

Comment: then you will need to build a function that reloads the views for you and call it every time you want to update the data.

Comment: When I Pop a viewcontroller, if I do it inside viewwillappear (in that viewcontroller) it should work. Right?

Comment: Yup, add breakpoints if you want to see exactly what gets called when though.

Comment: I don't know whats wrong with this. I made a few tests and i save the context with success. But when I pop the into VC3 it's like the results aren't updated yet... Not sure if this makes sense. Do you have any idea why is this happening? (Now the viewwillappear is working ok. I tested and it's working ok). Perhaps it has something to do with coredata updating...

Comment: Either way I'd sure could use some help!

Comment: Make sure you aren't overwriting your data from viewDidload in VC3.

Comment: i change a few things and it's working ok. Thanks (context issues).